# Calling method with returned variable from main

Tags: java, string, methods, program-entry-point

Currently have a program that has 2 classes, one class is for the main method,  and the other is for strings.

Main method is below, and I am trying to call the method getString, which just takes user input and stores as a string.
After getString has been run, I also want to run getReverse, which uses a short algorithm to reverse the string and then return it.

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ReverseString test1 = new ReverseString();
    test1.getString();
    test1.getReverse(inputString);
}
```

Class for strings:

```
public class ReverseString {

public ReverseString()
{

}

public String getString()
{
    String inputString = "";
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter string: ");
    inputString = keyboard.nextLine(); 
    return inputString;
}

public String getReverse(String inputString)
{
    String temp = "";
    for(int i = inputString.length(); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        temp = temp + inputString.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    return temp;

}
```

The program takes a string correctly, but will not run the second method after the first method has been called.

Comment: Start from learning basic programming things like variables, functions and so on.

Comment: besides that the issue that it does not compile because inputString is not known in method main. It will return IndexOutOfBounds since String#length gives the length and String#charAt works on index which is 0 based.

Comment: @Redlab would it work better if inputString was defined in main rather than in the class?

Comment: see the answer of @xenteros

Comment: You must be kidding. Your code already contains several examples of how to invoke a method and assign the returned result to a variable. By the way, you can implement your `getReverse` method as easy as `return new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();`…

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ReverseString test1 = new ReverseString();
    String inputString = test1.getString();
    inputString = test1.getReverse(inputString);
}
```

would fix the issue, but you should also do some refactoring. **Always** start class names with capital letter.